# VB2010 Parse Json response into a listview

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a json response that is looking like this

```
{"RandomUsername1":
{"Name":"Aaron Baker","Team":"Mavericks","Town":"Chester","Scores":{"lowest":1,"highest":10,"average":5}},
"RandomUsername2":
{"Name":"Dan Williams","Team":"Lions","Town":"Doncaster","Scores":{"lowest":0,"highest":8,"average":4}},
"RandomUsername3":
{"Name":"Oliver Smith","Team":"Hudsons","Town":"Oxford","Scores":{"lowest":4,"highest":14,"average":9}}
}
```

I have been using this code when there has been 1 key but when there are multiple keys for example "RandomUsername1","RandomUsername2","RandomUsername3" I am stuck and not sure how to modifiy the code to be displayed in a listview where all the users are listed.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports app_functions
Imports System.Net

Public Class UserInfo

    Private Const UserUrl As String = "https://www.anysitename/userinfo"


    Public Shared Function GetUser() As UserInfo

        If Not app_funcs.CanWeCallAPI Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim www As New WebClient()
        Dim res As Byte() = www.UploadValues(UserUrl, AuthHeader)
        Dim strRes As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res)

        Dim err As String = app_funcs.DetectError(strRes)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(err) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return Deserialize(strRes)


    End Function


    Public Shared Function Deserialize(json As [String]) As UserInfo
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UserInfo)(json)
    End Function

End Class
```

If someone could give me some pointers it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: The formatting of that JSON isn't great - you're ending up with three distinct objects types with the name of each being `RandomUserX`. Do you have control over that?

Comment: I have no control over that at all, there could be even more passed back, currently it is 3 randomuser but could go upto 10 different usernames

Comment: You don't have any nice solution at this point. You could create a transitional object that contains 10 property names RandomUsernameX and then convert it to a list into your "good" object. The other option is to use a .net library that allows you to parse the json yourself instead of automatically desirializing or that allows you to have more complex desirialization.